# If else Function with several conditions -Python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I am trying to calculate the final revenue of my dataset. My dataset has several revenue streams, but given some conditions (that I will explain later) the revenue per client will be calculated differently for the final revenue.

I am not very comfortable creating functions yet so I'm not sure where I am making mistakes.

**Dataframe examples:**

```
ClientId   Sector    Class    Rev1    Rev2    Rev3
1          Sect_1    B        5       1       0 
2          Sect_2    A        5.5     2       0
3          Sect_3    B        6       1.5     1
4          Sect_4    A        5       1       1.5
5          Sect_5    B        5       2       1
```

I want to create a 7th column 'Final_Rev' given the following **conditions**:

```
- If 'Sector' = (Sect_3 or Sect_4) : 'Final_Rev' = Rev2 + Rev3
- OR if 'Class' = ("A") : 'Final_Rev' = Rev2 + Rev3
- Otherwise 'Final_Rev' = Rev1
```

**Expected Output** should be the following:

```
ClientId   Sector    Class    Rev1    Rev2    Rev3    Final_Rev
1          Sect_1    B        5       1       0       5
2          Sect_2    A        5.5     2       0       2
3          Sect_3    B        6       1.5     1       2.5
4          Sect_4    A        5       1       1.5     2.5
5          Sect_5    B        5       2       1       5
```

I have tried to create the following function but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
def Final_Rev():
    
    if Sector in ['Sect_3','Sect_4'] or Class == 'A':
        return df['Rev2'] + df['Rev3']
    else: 
        return df['Rev1']

df['Final_Rev'] = df.apply(Final_Rev, axis=1)
```

I have found an R solution that does what I want but I don't know how to convert it to python:

```
Final_Rev := ifelse(test = (Sector %in% c("Sect_3","Sect_4")|Class == "A"),
             yes = Rev2 + Rev3,
             no = Rev1
```

If someone could help me solve this, it would be really appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: what is ```return dfc_optimized['RealizedPLGBP']```

Comment: Sorry, modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['Final_Rev'] = np.where(df['Sector'].isin(['Sect_3','Sect_4']) | (df['Class'] == 'A'), 
                           df['Rev2'] + df['Rev3'], 
                           df['Rev1'])
```

Output:

```
   ClientId  Sector Class  Rev1  Rev2  Rev3  Final_Rev
0         1  Sect_1     B   5.0   1.0   0.0        5.0
1         2  Sect_2     A   5.5   2.0   0.0        2.0
2         3  Sect_3     B   6.0   1.5   1.0        2.5
3         4  Sect_4     A   5.0   1.0   1.5        2.5
4         5  Sect_5     B   5.0   2.0   1.0        5.0
```

Comment: `.isin({'Sect_3', 'Sect_4'})` is faster than `.isin(['Sect_3','Sect_4'])`, and then you get essentially my answer (which somehow was downvoted).

Answer (score 2):

apply takes a [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) as its first argument which takes the column or row as a pandas.Series, so your function needs to take this as an argument.

```
import pandas as pd

def foo(ds):
    if ds['A'] == 1:
        return 26
    elif ds['B'] == 4:
        return 27
    else:
        return 2*ds['A'] + 3*ds['B']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'], data = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
df['C'] = df.apply(foo, axis=1)

    A   B   C
0   1   2   26
1   3   4   27
2   5   6   28
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired columns with a single expression:

```
df['Final_Rev'] = df['Rev1'].where(
    ~(df['Sector'].isin({'Sect_3', 'Sect_4'}) | (df['Class'] == 'A')),
    df['Rev2'] + df['Rev3'])
```

This is the fastest approach because it doesn't require `apply` at all.

Generally speaking and for readability, I would recommend to make masks corresponding to each sub-clause of your condition. In your case, there are two possible results (either `rev1` or `rev2 + rev3`). The first is a default value, the second depends on a single condition: `Sector in {'Sect_3', 'Sect_4'} or Class == 'A'`. Therefore:

```
mask = df['Sector'].isin({'Sect_3', 'Sect_4'}) | (df['Class'] == 'A')
df['Final_Rev'] = df['Rev1']  # default value
df.loc[mask, 'Final_Rev'] = df.loc[mask, 'Rev2'] + df.loc[mask, 'Rev3']
```

If you insist on calling a Python function on every row, you can also do that, but it will be way slower:

```
def myfunc(r):
    if r.Sector == 'Sect_3' or r.Sector == 'Sect_4' or r.Class == 'A':
        return r.Rev2 + r.Rev3
    return r.Rev1

df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)

# out:
0    5.0
1    2.0
2    2.5
3    2.5
4    5.0
```

**Performance**:

Why do I say the `.where()` form is the fastest?  Because it is all vectorized, and there is no need for repeated calls into a Python function.

Here is a test:

```
n = int(1e5)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ClientId': np.arange(n),
    'Sector': np.random.choice([f'Sect_{k}' for k in range(1, 8)], size=n),
    'Class': np.random.choice(list('ABCDEF'), size=n),
    'Rev1': np.random.randint(0, 20, size=n) * 0.5,
    'Rev2': np.random.randint(0, 20, size=n) * 0.5,
    'Rev3': np.random.randint(0, 20, size=n) * 0.5,
})
%timeit df['Rev1'].where(~(df['Sector'].isin({'Sect_3', 'Sect_4'}) | (df['Class'] == 'A')), df['Rev2'] + df['Rev3'])
10.9 ms ± 417 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
2.34 s ± 8.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The first form is **over 200x faster**!

Comment: Don't know who downvoted you (I upvoted your comment),but thanks for the explanation, especially for the improved version! ;) Perhaps your initial ```np.where```  approach is "less straight forward" as the other answers, which resemble more an "excel type" IF Function. At least that's my perception as a Python novice